# nuxt sitemap not working properly when used with nuxt-i18n

Tags: nuxt.js, sitemap, nuxt-i18n

When setup the config for nuxt-i18n in nuxt sitemap config the sitemap is not rendering properly.

```
sitemap: {
     hostname: 'http://localhost:8080',
     cacheTime: 600000,
     gzip: true,
     i18n: {
       defaultLocale: 'en',
       routesNameSeparator: '___'
     }
},
```

This is the output of sitemap when enable i18n in the config.
[image]

But when i18n is not used in the sitemap config

```
 sitemap: {
    hostname: 'http://localhost:8080',
    cacheTime: 600000,
    gzip: true
  },
```

This is the output of sitemap 
[image]

Since the project does have multilanguage so I need to setup the i18n config for the sitemap so that the sitemap could have alternate link of all the multilange as shown in the image below
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's only a rendering issue on your browser, due to the xml namespace of the elements `<xhtml:link>`. Your browser will convert the XML rendering to a XHTML page rendering because it see a know "xhtml:*" namespace.

Check the source code of the sitemap.xml, you will see that your XML file is correct.

Comment: Thanks @nicolas yes it seems to be the problem of browser render if check in the source code then it seems to work fine.

Btw for any the custom URL that I'm using it doesn't seems to set xhtml tag

Comment: Btw will there be any problem if issue with browser for rendering.XML? Since this will only be used by crawler bot no human will use it so should not be a problem right?